# auto_commit is still enabled although I prepend "START TRANSACTION" in mysql

Tags: mysql

When I check the official documentation of [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) or [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/start-transaction),

they say that `auto_commit` is disabled when **`START TRANSACTION`** is used.
But In my code It seemed not properly working. Did I do something wrong? Any Help would be appreciated!

```sql
SELECT @@autocommit; -- 1 (enabled)
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @@autocommit; -- 1 (I thought it should be zero.)
COMMIT;
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland No, `@@autocommit` is session setting, not global one.

Comment: @Akina whether `@@autocommit` is global or session variable, I think What I marked in code above should be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, autocommit is disabled. But the option value is not altered.

```
thread 1                                 |  thread 2
=========================================|==============================================
SELECT @@autocommit; -- 1 (enabled)      |
START TRANSACTION;                       |
SELECT @@autocommit; -- 1                |
    -- but autocommit is disabled !!!    |
INSERT INTO test (id) SELECT 1;          |
                                         |  SELECT * FROM test;   -- empty output
COMMIT;                                  |
                                         |  SELECT * FROM test;   -- row id=1 returned
```

The setting defines does the autocommit is applied out of the transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! By the way if `@@autocommit` is disabled below TEST table should be empty. but It has one `name = hello` record. Can you explain why this record was committed? although `@@autocommit` is disabled?

```
create table TEST(
    name varchar(30) unique
);

select * from TEST;

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO TEST(name) VALUE('hello');
INSERT INTO TEST(name) VALUE('hello'); -- error occur 
INSERT INTO TEST(name) VALUE('hello');
INSERT INTO TEST(name) VALUE('hello');

COMMIT;
```

Comment: @JohnSmith The row added within a transaction is visible in this transaction even without commit.